# From where the hand of the thief should be amputated?

Tags: fiqh, punishment

Quran orders:

> وَالسَّارِ‌قُ وَالسَّارِ‌قَةُ فَاقْطَعُوا أَيْدِيَهُمَا جَزَاءً بِمَا
>   كَسَبَا نَكَالًا مِّنَ اللَّـهِ وَاللَّـهُ عَزِيزٌ حَكِيمٌ
>
> [As for] the thief, the male and the female, amputate their hands in
>   recompense for what they committed as a deterrent [punishment] from
>   Allah. And Allah is exalted in Might and Wise. http://tanzil.net/#5:38

From where the hand should be amputated? Only fingers? From wrist? From elbow? Or other?

What is the reasoning for your answer?

Please specify your answer in according to related school of Fiqh (Hnafi, Shafei, Hanbali, Maliki, Jafari)

Comment: no amputation, it is about stopping him to steal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Imam Muhammad-al-Taqi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_al-Taqi) --peace be upon him-- only fingers should be amputated, since the Qur'an says,

> And the places of worship (المساجد) are for Allah (alone): So invoke not any one
>   along with Allah [[72:18](http://quran.com/72/18)]

As we know there are seven places which should lie on the ground during prostration, and two of these seven places are the palms of the two hands, the palms are for Allah and no one is allowed to amputate them as such a punishment.